# I have set interstitial ads like this code get all time error code com.facebook.ads.AdError@e0e1b7a

Tags: java, android-studio, admob, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I have recently tried to integrate FB interstitial ads to android ads and I turn on test mode.
Banner ads working fine but interstitial ads give this error com.facebook.ads.AdError@e0e1b7a

Here is my sample code :

```
 interstitial = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, "MyplacementId");
                InterstitialAdListener interstitialAdListener = new InterstitialAdListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                        Log.v(TAG, " interstitial ads not loaded"+adError.toString());
                 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                        Log.v(TAG, " interstitial ads  onclicked");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                        Log.v(TAG, " interstitial ads  login");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                        Log.v(TAG, " interstitial ads  displayed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                        Log.v(TAG, " interstitial ads  dismissed");
                    }
                };
                interstitial.loadAd(
                        interstitial.buildLoadAdConfig()
                                .withAdListener(interstitialAdListener)
                                .build());
```

Can anyone solve this ?